# How to create API wrapper for SQL stored procedure on Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-webapps

I have a stored procedure on Azure SQL database that I can execute with

```
EXEC [dbo].[PGET_JSON] @code = N'XYZ'
```

It returns FOR JSON result

```
{
  "XX": [
    {
      "DocOstatni": [
        {
          "Type": "Something",
          "Published": "2023-08-28T20:14:18.617",
          "Order": 1,
          "Name": "Something",
          "File": "PV_XXX_6.PDF",
        },{ ...
```

I need to create within Azure a (.net?) application that would expose the result of this stored procedure on public URL with parameter @code like

[myappid.azurewebsites.net/XYZ](https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/SVR)

that would return the output of stored procedure `[PGET_JSON]` with parameter `@code='XYZ'`.

What do I need on Azure and what type of Azure service should be used for it, should I use Azure web application or something else, what would be the easiest and least expensive solution?

I already have an Azure web app and perhaps It would be better to add the one sipmle API to the existing app?

Comment: Consider an [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) to build a serverless REST API.

Comment: If I already have an Azure web app, would not it be much less expensive to add the rest api to the existing app?

Answer (score 1):

> If I already have an Azure web app, would not it be much less expensive to add the rest api to the existing app?

Having a consumption-based function app is less expensive than using Azure Web app.

As @Dan Guzmann suggested to use Azure Function.

I have used Azure function to get the stored procedure. It worked for me.

#My Stored Procedure
[image]

I have used HTTP Trigger in azure function.

**#My code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace FunctionApp6
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string code = req.Query["code"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please provide a valid code parameter.");
            }

            string connectionString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("PGET_JSON", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter (command))
                    {
                        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                        if (dataTable.Rows.Count>0)
                        {
                            
                            string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);

                            return new OkObjectResult(result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return new NotFoundObjectResult("No data found");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
[{"Id":123,"Name":"Vivek"}]
```

**#Local:**
[image]

[image]

**#AZURE:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am using existing web app right now... But the routing stops working after publishing to Azure...

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Could you please let me know which framework web app you using or is it `.net` console app